# Connection failed to dockarized MySQL service

Tags: mysql, docker

I have dockarized MySQL container running. When I try to connect to this mysql-docker-service from other dockarized applications, it fails.

My docker-compose :

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysqlserver:
    image: mysql-server
    container_name: mysqlcontainer
    build:
      context: mysql-module/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: mysql-module/mysql.env
    networks: 
      - backend
    volumes: 
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports: 
      - 8001:3306

  users:
    image: users
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 7171:7171
    env_file: ./api.env
    networks: 
      - backend

networks: 
  backend:
    driver: "bridge"
```

MySQL dockerfile :

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server:latest

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE userservice

ADD sql-scripts/createUsers.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

I get database credentials from external file.
`MYSQLDBGATEWAY=root:7890@tcp(mysqlcontainer://mysqlserver:8001)/userservice?parseTime=true`

> Error getting user details dial tcp: lookup mysqlcontainer://mysqlserver:8001: no such host

What am I missing here? This is my first dockerized MySQL work.

Also in `sql-scripts/createUsers.sql` file I have :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS managerMinQuota (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  plan varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  minLimit int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But this is not created at run time.

Comment: Inside the container network you must use 3306

Comment: @Max `MYSQLDBGATEWAY=root:7890@tcp(mysqlcontainer://mysqlserver:3306)/userservice?parseTime=true`
is this the only change I need to make?

Comment: For the table you must wait mysql start, then execute script

Comment: @Max `Error getting user details dial tcp: lookup mysqlcontainer://mysqlserver:3306: no such host`